# How to set an environment variable to file contents in fish

Tags: fish

My config.fish file for fish shell has something like the following:

`set -x MY_VARIABLE "Hello World!"`

How could I get the results from reading the first line of a text file:

`set -x MY_VARIABLE read_file('hello.txt')`

Is there some way to do this in Fish?  I cant use cat and a subshell like I would in bash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a subcommand: `set -x MY_VARIABLE (head -1 hello.txt)`. Or use the read command: `read -x MY_VARIABLE < hello.txt`.

Comment: @mcha Use command substitution and a for loop: `for line in (hello.txt); echo line; end`

Comment: thanks @Kurtis, I ended up doing the same thing except that I had to use `cat` before the filename! Like this `for line in (cat ~/.vpn/work_hosts); echo line; end`

Comment: @mcha should be `echo $line`